# Gitlab CI/CD Pipeline - Get list of Modified files

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am running the below command in my pipeline and it throws an error that
git command not found

`git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r`

I am trying to capture list of changed files in my pipeline , if there is another way we can achieve this please share.

Comment: Please share at least the beginning of your .gitlab-ci.yml file (which would include the image your pipeline is using).

Comment: I was using Postgres image in the begining , now I am using alpine/git image and now its working . Thanks for your response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using alpine/git image in .gitlab-ci.yml file does the trick
below sample code

```
job a:
  image: alpine/git
  script:
    - git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r

job b:
  image: postges
  script:
    - echo ""
```

Comment: Typo `apline` instead of `alpine`